# Use of undefined constant INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46 error while doing payment on stripe, Laravel

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, cpanel, laravel-6

I am getting this error while doing payment on stripe Laravel.

> Use of undefined constant INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46 - assumed
>   'INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46'

My controller:

```
$stripe_secret = config('services.stripe.secret');
$stripe = Stripe::make($stripe_secret);
$charge = $stripe->charges()->create([
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'amount' => (float)$amount,
    'source' => $payment_token,
    'description' => '',
    'receipt_email' => $receipt_email,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](https://www.bram.us/2019/12/18/avoid-guzzle-6-5-0-aka-how-to-fix-use-of-undefined-constant-intl_idna_variant_uts46-on-centos-6/) describes the issue you're having. To fix the issue you should avoid guzzle 6.5.0.